# Objective C String Comparison. Weird Behavior?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

I'm just doing a plain old string comparison for an if condition and I got a weird behavior. In the console, I got the following and fell off my seat.

```
(lldb) po [@"Puc X-1234" rangeOfString:@"Puc"]
nil
```

How can this be?

Comment: Are you running in Debug or Release mode?  lldb doesn't always represent the true state of things, especially when the Release optimizations are applied.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`rangeOfString:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/rangeOfString:) return `NSRange`, which is not an object but `po` is for print objc object

try `p (NSRange)[@"Puc X-1234" rangeOfString:@"Puc"]`

the reason it print `nil` is that the returning `NSRange` is `(0,3)`, then the debugger take the `0` part and assume it is `id` type, and print `nil`

Comment: You beat me to it. (Voted)